# Архитектура приложения(хранение записей)

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, вопрос такой. Строю архитектуру свой програмки, по типу органайзера. Не могу понять как правильно хранить записи(задания) на конкретные сутки. План такой: открывается окно по типу календаря, выбирается число на которое хочу внести Задание, открывается новое окно в котором можно записать до 10 разных задач(все они в разных полях(клетки)). Проблема в том что, в каком формате или есть какие то уже придуманные решения подобного, на 1 месяц 28-31 день может быть по все 10 задач заполнены и работа с файлом будет в виде оповещений на ПК. Меня смущает факт, создания самого файла 1 XML на 31 день, или отдельный создавать. Подскажите по архитектуре, всю голову поломал, заранее не судите строго, не могу решить этот вопрос сам. Спасибо.

Comment: Мне кажется тут дело не в правильности, а по большей части в том, что удобней использовать вам при разработке. Вот к примеру я пишу всегда в основном небольшие утилиты, мне достаточно `JSON`, я очень люблю с ним работать. Мой сайт написан на Asp.net Core и для хранения там простых данных для моих проектов я использую `SQLite`. Смотрите сами что вам удобней для этой задачи. Как по мне, у вас не так много данных и спокойно можно разместить все в JSON или XML. Если же это не вся задача и данных будет в разы больше, то используйте базу, создавайте таблицы со связями.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать любую NoSql базу данных, сохраняя в ней напрямую ваши объекты. К сожалению, работающих in process nosql баз данных не так много, и для большинства популярных решений, вроде MongoDB придётся устанавливать сервис в ОС. Это может быть частью инсталляции вашего продукта. Но если это вас пугает, вы можете использовать SQLite как движок БД, по-прежнему сохраняя туда данные в JSON. В этом случае придётся написать обёртку для сериализации/десериализации данных в БД. У меня есть такая, могу в принципе целиком скинуть в виде gist.

Comment: Вообще то есть отличная встраиваемая NoSQL база данных [LiteDB](http://www.litedb.org/), рекомендую, вполне успешно использовал в собственном проекте.